# Over prime fields, are all monic irreducible polynomials primitive?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

If $P(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, prime $p$, is monic and irreducible, is $P(x)$ also primitive?

Comment: In [which sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial)?

Comment: @DuncanTownsend  What is the context? What did you attempted?

Comment: In a word, *No!*. For example $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$, but it is not primitive, because it roots are fourth roots of unity and hence won't generate the multiplicative group of the splitting field.

Comment: Some care needs to be used when using the word *primitive* to describe elemnts/polynomials over finite fields. The other meaning of *a primitive polynomial* (see @Anne's link) is only interesting when the ring of coefficients has non-trivial divisibility theory, so is uninteresting here when working over a field.

Comment: A possibly more common (and more confusing) overloading of the term occurs when people discuss *primitive elements* carelessly. In the case of finite fields, a primitive element is always a generator of the multiplicative group. Elsewhere in field theory an element  is called primitive, if it generates the desired extension field by itself. I elaborated on the difference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959259/11619).

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for clarifying. I mean it in the "field theory" sense.

Comment: Seems that @JyrkiLahtonen has the answer: "no". Thanks for the example!