# Primitive element of a finite field whose powers do not lie inside the prime subfield

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $p$ be a prime, and consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Fix any $n\ge1$, and consider the field extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p$.  If $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a multiplicative generator, then $\alpha$ is also a primitive element, that is, $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}=\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$, and further, the set $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.  Therefore, we can conclude that the elements $\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\not\in\mathbb{F}_p$.

In the above statement, I could conclude 'non-membership' in $\mathbb{F}_p$ by using linear independence over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Is a converse of this true, that is, must 'non-membership' imply linear independence over $\mathbb{F}_p$?  Specifically, for $n,m\ge1$, if $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a multiplicative generator such that the elements $\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{m-1}\not\in\mathbb{F}_p$, then must $m\le n$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is primitive then its lowest power in the prime field is that with exponent $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$. BTW, finite field people reserve the term *primitive element* to mean *a generator of the multiplicative group*. This differs from what's common elsewhere in field theory. [My elaboration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959259/11619).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p=2$ and $n=3$, and let $\alpha$ be a generator of the multiplicative group, so that $\alpha$ has order $7$.

Then none of $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5,\alpha^6$ lie in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Yet $7>3$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand:  $\alpha$ is the root of an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb F_2$, and $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb F_8$ over $\mathbb F_2$, correct?

Comment: How do we know that none of $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5,\alpha^6$ lie in $\mathbb{F}_2$?  Because if one of them were $1$ then the order wouldn’t be $7$, and if one of them were $0$ then we would have $\alpha^7=0$, not $1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner (i) Yes, we can assume $\alpha, \alpha^2,\alpha^4$ are the roots of the irreducible $X^3+X+1$, and $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ is an $\mathbb{F}_2$ basis of $\mathbb{F}_8$.  (ii)  The multiplicative group is cyclic of order $7$, $\alpha$ is a generator, so these are six distinct invertible elements of order $7$, so do not belong to $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Yes, I think we can abstract out the example of @ancientmathematician to conclude that, following the notations in the question, `non-membership' is characterized by the condition $(m-1)(p-1) < p^n - 1$.